# React Native - java.lang.SecurityException: com.app/com.app.MainActivity UserHandle{0} is not a launcher activity

Tags: android, react-native, android-securityexception

The app was getting SecurityException reports from Google firebase crash report tool. This is an error log of the crash:

```
Exception java.lang.SecurityException: com.veta/com.veta.MainActivity UserHandle{0} is not a launcher activity
android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1599)
android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel (DatabaseUtils.java:188)
android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel (DatabaseUtils.java:140)
android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert (ContentProviderNative.java:476)
android.content.ContentResolver.insert (ContentResolver.java:1280)
android.content.AsyncQueryHandler$WorkerHandler.handleMessage (AsyncQueryHandler.java:96)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:207)
android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:61)
```

This my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
    <permission
      android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature" />
      <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity 
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.INFO" />
          </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="filter_feed">
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data android:scheme="com.veta" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
</application>
```

I got this error from Sony E5663 device. I checked out other questions asked on StackOverflow but it does not help to solve my problem. I am new to React native. Please, any can help to solve this problem. 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you modified the AndroidManifest file ?

Comment: I modified AndroidManifest file to add SplashActivity. But I check it on Samsung Galaxy A5 device. It is working perfectly. @Rahul

Comment: what is os version of device ?

Comment: Android OS: 6.0 @Rahul

Comment: Try to give run time permission for camera and other thing if you are using in MainActivity